# Cant find the fix for my program at LeetCode Challenge of PrimeNumbers

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging, primes

I have tried several ways changing my code in LeetCode but I can't find the fix,  the challenge is the next one :

<<Count the number of prime numbers less than a non-negative number, n.

Example:

Input: 10
Output: 4
Explanation: There are 4 prime numbers less than 10, they are 2, 3, 5, 7.>>

My proposal code is the next one:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    class Solution {
        public int countPrimes(int n) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int cont = 0;
        int prime = 0;
        prime = sc.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int [prime];
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = i;
            cont = 0;
            
            for(int y = 1; y< a.length; y++) {
                if(a[i] % y == 0) {
                    cont ++;
                }
            }
            if (cont == 2) {
                sum ++;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Meanwhile the error marks as follows:

```
Submission Result: Compile Error More Details 
Line 7: error: cannot find symbol [in __Driver__.java] int ret = new Solution().countPrimes(param_1); ^ symbol: method countPrimes(int) location: class Solution
Run Code Status: Runtime Error
×
Run Code Result:
Your input
10
Your answer
java.util.NoSuchElementException
  at line 937, java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor
  at line 1594, java.base/java.util.Scanner.next
  at line 2258, java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt
  at line 2212, java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt
  at line 8, Solution.countPrimes
  at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 84, __Driver__.main
Show Diff
Runtime: N/A
```

Please help!

Comment: Leetcode provides all the inputs for the problem as part of the function's parameters, what are you taking the input for integer variable "prime" for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This'll also pass through:

```
public class Solution {
    public static final int countPrimes(int n) {
        // mapping for if the number is divisible by prime numbers, which would make that number a composite number
        boolean[] notPrime = new boolean[n];
        // counting prime numbers
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            // If the index of notPrime would be false, we have a prime number, we go through the if, otherwise we continue
            if (notPrime[i] == false) {
                // Increment the number of prime numbers
                count++;

                // Look into future numbers
                for (int j = 2; i * j < n; j++) {
                    // find composite numbers and set their indices to true
                    notPrime[i * j] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-primes/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.
- [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)
- [YouTube 1](https://youtu.be/eKp56OLhoQs)
- [YouTube 2](https://youtu.be/PypkiVlTRa4)

Comment: This is the only solution that actually worked, but  I don't seem to fully understand its logic... Would you mind explaining why are you using an array of booleans, as well as why do u have that value in the nested for condition <  i * j  > ? thank you lots Emma

Comment: hmm..are you sure this is the only one it worked...?

Comment: Thank you Emma for the references! (: I also want to thank you @aran I tried your proposal as well, and as you could note, it didn't passed the time test, I'm guessing because of the memory use, but I really appreciate your time and effort (:

Comment: I got really confused about the type of test, and was wrong about my comment. Glad you could fix this thanks to @Emma mate!

Answer (score 1):

You got confused with the input/output part: you don't need any scanner to do this, just:

```
 class Solution 
 {
      public static int countPrimes(int n) 
       {
          int sum = 0;
           int a[] = new int [n];
           for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                a[i] = i;
                int  cont = 0;
            
                for(int y = 1; y< a.length; y++) {
                    if(a[i] % y == 0) {
                       cont++;
                     }
                 }
          if (cont == 2) {
              sum++;
          }
        }
       return sum; //this is the output
    }
        
     public static void main(String args[])
    ´{
        countPrimes(10); //this is the input
     }
}
```

### Proof:

[image]

---

Et voilá. LeetCode accepts the input (10) and the output (4). That's all you need :)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer gets a `scanner` object which is not needed therefore you could remove it.

You also create an `array` which will decrease performance, which I recommend not using as you do not need to display the prime numbers but only keep track of them.

```
public static int countPrimes(int n) {

    int sum=0;

    for(int i = n; i > 1; i-- ){
        
        int count = 0; //Keep track of the number of primes.
        
        for(int j = 2; j < i; j++){
            if(i % j == 0){
                count++;
            }
        }
        
        if(count==0) {
            sum++;
        }
      
    }

    return sum;

    }
```